# How to keep "true" NAs while aggregating hierarchical or grouped time series using aggts?

Tags: r, time-series

I am using the the aggts() function from the hts package to aggregate my hierarchical time series.
The function replaces NAs by zeros before the time series are aggregated.
This is useful if at least one of the observations is not NA. But if all observations for the given time are NA I want to keep NA instead of 0.

**Edit (working example):**

```
library(hts)

df <- data.frame(
  AB = c(5, 10, 15, NA, 25, 30, NA, 40)
  , AA = c(10, 20, 30, NA, 50, 60, 70, 80)
)

hts_object <- hts(df)

> aggts(hts_object)
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 8 
Frequency = 1 
  Total AB AA
1    15  5 10
2    30 10 20
3    45 15 30
4     0  0  0
5    75 25 50
6    90 30 60
7    70  0 70
8   120 40 80
```

But what I need is:

```
> aggts(hts_object)
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 8 
Frequency = 1 
  Total AB AA
1    15  5 10
2    30 10 20
3    45 15 30
4    NA NA NA
5    75 25 50
6    90 30 60
7    70 NA 70
8   120 40 80
```

**Edit2 (after updating 'hts' package):**

```
> aggts(hts_object)
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 8 
Frequency = 1 
  Total AB AA
1    15  5 10
2    30 10 20
3    45 15 30
4    NA NA NA
5    75 25 50
6    90 30 60
7    NA NA 70
8   120 40 80
```

This is not what I was expecting. Maybe this will be more clear with some background information. Due to Covid-19 I have to flag several monthly data points as outliers. If the observations across all hierarchy levels are NAs, I would like to keep the NAs after aggregating the time series. But if not all observations at a specific hierarchy level are NAs the sum is required.

My real life business examples are:

- global outliers for all hierarchy levels (like for Covid-19)

  --> all aggregated time series should contain NA if all bottom time series are NA
- products with different market entry time (some time series have leading NAs)

  --> aggregated levels require sum(na.rm = TRUE)
- classic missing observations

  --> aggregated levels require sum(na.rm = TRUE) and maybe interpolating is required beforehand

Answer (score 1):

Now fixed in the dev version at https://github.com/earowang/hts

If the NAs are actually zeros, then replace them with zeros.

If they are really missing, then by definition the sum must be NA because you cannot know its value. You could replace them with estimates, or proceed with the data containing NAs. Some models, including ARIMA models, will handle NAs without a problem.

Comment: I tested the new version of the 'hts' package and provided more details above, because the current dev version is not implemented in the way I expected.

Comment: I saw your edit and I fully agree, if values are really missing, the sum must be NA. But a product hierarchy may contain time series with different launch dates. Each younger product results in a time series with NAs or zeros at the beginning. Zeros at the beginning of a time series will lower the forecast accuracy. I think the user should be responsible for interpolating missing values and therefore NA + NA = NA and NA + 10 = 10. It would be then much easier to automate hierarchical forecasts, if some of the time series have NAs at the beginning, by using na.trim(type="left") beforehand.

Comment: Young products should have zeros at the beginning as there were no sales before they were launched. These are not missing. Then the time series model used should allow for that behaviour. You probably need to use a count time series model.

Comment: I defenitely see your point here, but how do you then treat "true" zeros? Auto.arima performs worse if the time series starts with n zeros. It would be more comfortable to interpolate "true" missing values before, consider "true" NAs where all observations are NAs and use na.trim("left") to increase the forecast accuracy if the specific time series is shorter than the others. It would be more complex to cut off leading zeros, because there may be "true" zeros within the time series. For my understanding, only an already launched product can have zero sales.

Comment: I suggest you write your own forecasting function to filter leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider pre-processing the dataframe such that NA values are converted to zeros UNLESS the entire row contains only NAs:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  
  # label which rows contain only NAs
  plyr::adply(1, 
              .fun = function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  
  # in all columns with numeric data, convert NAs to zeros, UNLESS the row contains only NAs
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric),
                function(x) ifelse(is.na(x) & !V1, 0, x))) %>%
  
  # remove column of NA-only labels created in first step
  select(-V1) %>%
  
  hts() %>%
  aggts()
```

Result using dev version of `hts::aggts`:

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 8 
Frequency = 1 
  Total AB AA
1    15  5 10
2    30 10 20
3    45 15 30
4    NA NA NA
5    75 25 50
6    90 30 60
7    70  0 70
8   120 40 80
```